# How to break mvn project into multimodules?

Tags: java, maven, module

Is there any way to break a standard Spring Boot Maven project into multi modules?

Let's say i have a package for models, one for controllers, one for dao and another one for ui. Can i split them to separate modules somehow?

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate if matters.

Comment: Yes of course you can. create appropriate directories one for `model`, one for `controllers` one for `dao` and one for `ui` and parent which which handles it... this is so called a multi module build...

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible.
create a directory per each module in your project, and add for every one of the separate POM.
At the project root level at the main POM(reactor) you will reference each one of them.
Example for reactor :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>...</name>
    
   <modules>
        <module>sub-module-a</module>
        <module>sub-module-b</module>
        <module>sub-module-c</module>

    </modules>
    
</project>
```

And when you will build your project, you will do it from the reactor.
for more details you can check maven documentation:
https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html